# Beautifoul soup - getting all li elements from ul where only first li has specific class name

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have unordered list like this in HTML:

```
<ul> 
<li class="label">Equipement</li>
<li>Aluminum tyres</li>
<li>4x4</li>
<li>3. stop lights</li>
<li>Bluetooth</li>
</ul>
```

Only first `li` element in the `ul` list contains title of the list, other elements contain list of features that needs to be extracted in plain text.
I know how to locate that first `li` but I don't know how to select all other elements.

Consider that this `ul` doesn't have class and its in the HTML document with a lot of other `ul` elements. 
I can locate that `ul` through `li` with:

```
 (li.previousSibling).get_text()
```

but cannot extract all elements with `get_text()` , I'm getting:

> AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Also I need to extract all `li` except first one which holds title. I have several `ul` on page like this and they are all variable in lenght (have more or less `li` elements).

**EDIT**

My code so far. I'm finding elements with:

```
 carBasics = soup.select('li.label')

    for li in carBasics:
         if li.contents[0]=="Equipement":
            carAdditionalEquipement = (li.previousSibling).find_all('li')
```

> AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is to omit first `li`. 
No one gave answer to that so this is how I did it in the end:

```
for item in soup.select("ul li.labela"):
   if item.text=="Equipement":
       carAdditionalEquipement = li.parent.text[len(li.contents[0])+1:].strip().splitlines()
```

From that I'm getting nice list without first line which is taken out with `[len(li.contents[0])+1:]`.

Basically I'm chopping off lenght of firsts element from string list and splitting it than since there is newline char on the end of each list

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get(
    'yoururl')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')

for li in soup.select('ul li.labela'):
  if li.contents[0]=="Equipement":
    print(li.parent.text)
```

Comment: Yes I've removed it because I don't want to post it. I've seen you're link - you have extracted titles correctly. I need to extract everything below that title, all items till the end of the list in text form.

Comment: Majority of items have only single value. I have no problem getting that value or getting only 1st element in the list after title with nextSibling option. But Last 4-5 items have more li item below them. Best example is b'<li class="labela">Dodatna oprema vozila</li>'

Answer (score 1):

Use `find_next_siblings`()

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<ul>
<li class="label">Equipement</li>
<li>Aluminum tyres</li>
<li>4x4</li>
<li>3. stop lights</li>
<li>Bluetooth</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="label">Equipement</li>
<li>Aluminum tyres</li>
<li>4x4</li>
<li>3. stop lights</li>
<li>Bluetooth</li>
</ul>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select("ul li.label"):
    if item.text=="Equipement":
        siblings=[s.text for s in item.find_next_siblings('li')]
        print(siblings)
```

Edited the answer:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = requests.get('https://www.index.hr/oglasi/bmw-serija-5-3-0-xd/oid/1971034')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.select("ul li.labela"):
   if item.text=="Dodatna oprema vozila":
      siblings=[s.text for s in item.find_next_siblings('li')]
      print(siblings)
```

Comment: @Harvey I checked your code you had provides class name `label` instead `labela`.It is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use a css general sibling combinator and with bs4 4.7.1+ you can use :contains to specify the label text as well if known

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<ul> 
<li class="label">Equipement</li>
<li>Aluminum tyres</li>
<li>4x4</li>
<li>3. stop lights</li>
<li>Bluetooth</li>
</ul>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print([li.text for li in soup.select('.label:contains("Equipement") ~ li')])
```